# Accessing Server responce in jquery ajax error handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying ajax over cross domain. I always got error code 0 always. I have searched a lot of this and found this is due to restrictions of server headers.

When I check the ajax on Firebug, I can see the response from the server. So Only my issue is I need to get that response in error handler instead of success. But I am trying to print the response in error handler and I am getting empty

```
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         alert(xhr.responseText);
```

This is my ajax function look like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "externam_url",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: 'somedata',
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
            // do something with server response data
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         alert(xhr.responseText);

    }
```

So Please help me. My ajax is working perfectly fine, but how to read the ajax response data in "error" handler

Comment: Ref:- https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7868

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to Curl for Solution.

```
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'id'=>'Bar'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'external_url');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```